# How can I join table on value with string added

Tags: mysql, sql

How can I `Join` a table in this fashion:

```
SELECT * FROM TableA
JOIN TableB ON
TableA.col = 'http://google.com/'+TableB.col
```

The two tables relate to each other, except one table has a **string** `(like http://google.com)` in front of the value.

Comment: Have you tried that syntax?  It works in SQL Server as you have it.

Comment: Didn't that work? If so, did you get any error?

Comment: Well have you actually tried the query you've written above?

Comment: @AdrianCornish That expression is not a table name.

Comment: Also, I'm not greatly sure of this, but doing this might do bad things to query performance. To make sure, take a look at the `EXPLAIN` output for the version with and without string concatenation.

Comment: Thanks for all your help. This turned out to be another issue, but the `concat` tip improved what i was trying to do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT … FROM …
JOIN TableB ON 
TableA.col LIKE CONCAT('http://google.com/',TableB.col);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you write the query in the way you have written e.g.

```
    SELECT * 
    FROM TABLEA A 
         JOIN
         TABLEB B 
    ON(A.column1 = CONCAT('http://google.com',B.column1));
```

It should do your job done.

Comment: MySQL uses `CONCAT()` as in `CONCAT('http://google.com', B.column1)`, rather than the `||` used by some other RDBMS.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski - Yes, I realized I wrote `oracle` syntax and I was editing the answer to correct, but it prompted me the `human verification` :(